# Drop down in a PHP doesn't work in IE but works in Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I added a drop down to a PHP contact form which pops up in a jquery, it seems to work just fine with Firefox but does not submit when using IE.

URL: http://site.ctuchicago.com

Comment: Your link doesn't take me to a contact form... you should really post the code here.

Comment: http://ctuchicago.com/contact.txt => code is here

Comment: sheesh how do people use php...let alone try to debug it

Comment: @redsquare - PHP pays all my bills, and then some. Debugging is simple: print_r($brokenVar);

Comment: Karim I'm not sure I follow you

Comment: As far as I can tell from the source, there is nothing jQuery about this what do you mean by "pops up in a jquery"

Comment: Hey James the site opens this php with a jquery but i know that doesn't matter, you can see it by going to site.ctuchicago.com and clicking on "contact" on the left

Comment: Guys thanks for all the help but honestly I don't even know where to look when these tools check the code for errors, I'm a beginner

Comment: @karim - I'd rather clean bins I think! It just makes my eyes bleed looking at the code php allows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone else said,  welcome to wonderful world of webdesign.

I can only direct you to a tool I use when i have similar problems(besides my angerball, which is number one tool for cross browser css compatibility),  [**firebug for ie**](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html).

Answer (score 0):

Submits fine for me in IE7. Just got the confirmation e-mail, too.

Comment: my debugger indicates that this is a problem with jQuery code on this line: !option.attributes.value.specified?option.text:option.value... I looked for this bit in my jQuery 1.3.2 code and didn't find it. What version are you using? Try using the latest one, this could resolve your issue.